# How to use 2 or more different bootstrap theme in one angular 16 project?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui, ng

i'm doing with 2 theme firstly but i want to do for 3 modules so, I have 2 modules : Admin and Users. Both have 2 different theme of bootstrap like in admin pages using as dashboard purpose and for user pages  using front-end for user , theme. But when  use all scss/css and js files in index.html then style sheets and js are occuring conflicts and design is not displayed properly in any pages or we can say doing overlapping/messup. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVPCi.png)